# Mix C and C++ with CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a project written in C (on Linux) and now want to use a third-party C ++ library that provides .h and .c source files.

I renamed the .c file to .cpp and then include this library in the C project. However, the following error appears when compiled:

```
unknown type name ‘class’
```

> Added: The third-party library is here https://github.com/0xmalloc/c-log
>    The author say it's friendly to both C and C++

Comment: You can't #include .h files to C that contain declarations of C++ classes.

Comment: *"I renamed the .c file to .cpp"* - Why?

Comment: *"C ++ library that provides .h and .c source files"*  more like a C library.

Comment: Readme.md says it is good for "C/C++ language". Perhaps you should ask the author where to find a compiler for said language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options here:

- you make your whole project a C++ one - this doesn't mean you need to convert your C code to C++ but rather that you will probably have to touch this and that part of it and also go for a C++ and not C-only compiler
- provide wrappers - usually if you write C++ code in C style (no classes etc.) you will only have to do that `extern "C" void foo()`  routine for your C++ functions. However the moment you start working with features that C doesn't support you will have to provide wrappers for your C++ functionality so that it can be exposed to the C part of your application. Such procedure can be from very easy to incredibly complex. For example many modern C/C++ API also provide Python API. In order to do that without having to rewrite everything in Python the authors create wrappers that translate the C/C++ functionality to Python. Depending on how well this is done features of the target language (Python in case we go from C/C++ to Python) can be used to allow better error handling, type checking, readability, native (to the target language) data containers etc.

I do believe that the author of the library misled you since the library is clearly for C++ (the classes in the header are definitely the most obvious thing that just screams C++).